# Rewrite data stream in async filter with Quarkus and Reactor

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, project-reactor

I have a webhook from side service and I try to make a filter in front of the controller, for check signature. Like a Spring Security style, but unfortunately, it's Quarkus with Reactor.
In the controller, I have `null` and the debugger does even not achieve the controller method.

My targets are:

1. Check signature I need a header and body for it and `WebhookHandlerUtility` is not mt class and I can't change it. And `WebhookHandlerUtility.verifySignature(signature, body)` sync method and I can't change it.
2. I need to rewrite the stream because I expect to receive this data in the controller as a body.

What is the problem with my implementation and how to fix it?

```
@Provider
class SignatureFilter(
        private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
        private val webhookHandlerUtility: WebhookHandlerUtility
) : ContainerRequestFilter {

    private val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext) {
        executor.execute {
            val signature = requestContext.getHeaderString("signature")
            val body = requestContext.entityStream.reader().readText()

            if (!webhookHandlerUtility.verifySignature(signature, body)) {
                throw TerraSignatureVerificationException()
            }

            val payload = webhookHandlerUtility.parseWebhookPayload(body)
                    ?: throw TerraWebHookPayloadParseException()

            val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload.raw)
            val newInputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(json.toByteArray())

            requestContext.entityStream = newInputStream
        }
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/webHook")
class WebHookController(
        private val omronService: OmronService
) {

    @POST
    @Path("/device")//, 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun omronWebHook(req: HookDto): Uni<Response> {
        log.info("Received data: $req")
        return omronService.save(req)
                .map { Response.noContent().build() }
    }
}
```

```
2023-09-29 14:30:46,346 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.ser.han.ParameterHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Error occurred during parameter extraction: 
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: No bean found for required type [interface javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext] and qualifiers [[]]
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.bean(InstanceImpl.java:190)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.getInternal(InstanceImpl.java:211)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:97)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.parameters.ContextParamExtractor.extractParameter(ContextParamExtractor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ParameterHandler.handle(ParameterHandler.java:45)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:111)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:142)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:51)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:8)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:71)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:408)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$5.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$5.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:185)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2023-09-29 14:30:46,349 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Restarting handler chain for exception exception: 
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ParameterHandler.handle(ParameterHandler.java:66)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:111)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:142)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:51)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:8)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:71)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:408)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$5.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$5.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:185)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: No bean found for required type [interface javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext] and qualifiers [[]]
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.bean(InstanceImpl.java:190)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.getInternal(InstanceImpl.java:211)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:97)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.parameters.ContextParamExtractor.extractParameter(ContextParamExtractor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ParameterHandler.handle(ParameterHandler.java:45)
    ... 30 more

2023-09-29 14:30:46,358 INFO  [http-problem] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) status=400, title="Bad Request", detail="HTTP 400 Bad Request" 
Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot be called from response filter
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.jaxrs.ContainerRequestContextImpl.assertNotResponse(ContainerRequestContextImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.jaxrs.ContainerRequestContextImpl.setEntityStream(ContainerRequestContextImpl.java:158)
    at com.dfskjhzxk.terra.configuration.SignatureFilter.filter$lambda$0(SignatureFilter.kt:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to make the stacktrace more readable?

Comment: How? It's full stack trace after request

Comment: @Pavel I guess you can 1) remove everything below the actual problem, 2) make it as a code snippet not a quote.

Comment: Do you understand where the end of the actual problem is? If you say it will be part of the answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a request scoped bean from a thread that is not managed by Quarkus (as you are using your own executor).

A simple remedy would be to just access whatever you need from `ContainerRequestContext` in the `filter` method itself, instead of having the former being accessed in the lambda that is used as the `Runnable` for the thread